# What is the difference between suse professional and suse enterprise?

Tags: linux, opensuse, sles

I have looking to download the Suse Professional 11.

However, I have been to 2 websites, [the paid subscription version](https://www.suse.com/products/server/eval.html) and [opensuse, the free open source edition](http://www.opensuse.org/en/).

But none of them mention anything about the professional version.

What is the professional version:

- Is it paid version or open source?
- Is it for desktop or server?
- Where can I download version 11?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"SuSE Linux Professional" is the old name for openSuSE. So, you can just download openSuSE 11 instead.